# Why Jmeter tests take too much time to set up HTTPS TrustAll Socket Factory?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have set up JMeter to run Performance tests with 8 threads which will have different test loads. I am running the test using non GUI mode.

When I start test for the first time in a day, I see in the log file that first thread get stuck at one line with message "Setting up HTTPS TrsutAll Socket Factory". It stays there around 8-10 minutes and then tests resume without any issues.

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNQPs.jpg)

Due to this I am not able to get accurate result for my first thread.

Am I missing something in JMeter set up ? Really appreciate your input. TIA.

I have also tried recording logs and added Java.net.debug=all in systems.properties but it was no help as I was not able to see any errors and tests will start executing in 8-10 mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `Setting up HTTPS TrustAll Socket Factory` is something which should be done in milliseconds

[image]

As per [SSL Encryption](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl) chapter of JMeter documentation

> **The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc.** This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers.

so the message is about JMeter creating a special [SSL Socket Factory which trusts all certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https) (expired, missing certificate in chain, unknown issuer, etc.

You can try:

- [Increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to `DEBUG` level, maybe you will see what JMeter is doing for such long period of time
- If JMeter will be "stuck" or "hangs" - take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and see what exactly threads are doing and what exactly they're waiting for
- Additionally you can use a profiler tool like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/features/) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) - it will give you the most comprehensive information
- if nothing helps you can just use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to remove sample results for first 8-10 minutes of your test but it's rather a workaround than a solution